# Get certificates stored on smart card on Windows Mobile 6

Tags: c#, smartcard, windows-mobile-6

I develop an Windows Mobile 6 Application for a PDA (with Compact Framework 3.5). My PDA has a smart card reader. When a card is inserted, I would get all the certificates stored inside. I have already do that in a desktop application with success but when I try the same code on my mobile, I don't find the certificate! So, I've tried differents solutions but nothing works!

Here my code:

```
X509Store test = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
test.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

if (test.Certificates.Count > 0)
{
     foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in test.Certificates)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Certificate: " + cert.ToString());
     }
}
```

Have you got an idea?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: There are no exceptions, no errors. My code indicates me there are no certificate stored on my smart card.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to open Root store in LocalMachine? I don't think that you will ever find a certificate from a smartcard there. I would try to open `X509Store test = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);`.

Comment: Thank you for your response Pepo. Sadly, I've already tried with these parameters and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an exception? If you only see empty store maybe it is a problem with certificate propagation from smartcard to windows cert store.

In desktop windows systems there is a service **Certificate Propagation** (CertPropSvc) that

> Copies user certificates and root certificates from smart cards into
>   the current user's certificate store, detects when a smart card is
>   inserted into a smart card reader, and, if needed, installs the smart
>   card Plug and Play minidriver.

I don't know if such service exists in Windows Mobile 6 or any mobile windows OS.

I would sugest you make research (my 2 minutes effort on google didn't bring any positive results).

Or you could try to use PKCS#11 library to access and use certificates and private keys stored on smart card. SmartCard vendors often distribute a PKCS#11 library with drivers for the smartcard.

There are some opensource .NET projects that enable you to communicate with PKCS#11 library (which is often written in C) like
[PKCS11Interop](http://pkcs11interop.net/) or [NCryptoki](http://www.ncryptoki.com/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. But after several tests, it seems that the libraries "PKCS11Interop" and "NCryptoki" don't work on Windows Mobile 6 ...